# How can I create a PayPal link that will send money to a specific e-mail address?

Tags: paypal

This if for an internal CMS, so it's not public facing. I have my publishers that I need to pay via PayPal. I'd like to be able to click one link and it goes directly to a PayPal page with their email address filled in and a particular value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind, found it.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=buynow

Comment: Hijacking top answer to also say paypal.me is a service that solves exactly this: e.g., https://paypal.me/tomfuertes/5

Comment: @TomFuertes Unfortunately, PayPal.me does not allow anything other than amount and currency in the URL, which makes it useless for services/goods payments.

Answer (score 9):

For those that don't want to, or can't use PayPal.me links, here is a Uri that will work with the new and old PayPal UI.

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
?cmd=_xclick
&business=email@address.com
&tax=0
&currency=USD
&item_name=NAME
&item_number=NUMBER
&quantity=1
&amount=2.50
```

Answer (score 5):

### For physical items

A basic setup for physical goods (with shipping):

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?&cmd=_xclick&business=info@test.com&currency_code=EUR&amount=0.01&item_name=Test description
```

It will add `&item_name` parameter that indicates to PayPal API that you are selling physical items that need to be shipped to the customer. A shipping address will be displayed on the payment screen and the items will be hidden behind a drop-down menu at the top/right corner (the shopping cart).

**PayPal link generator (3rd party)**

There is a pure JS lazy PayPal link generation tool over here:

http://www.itaynoy.com/sites/paypal_button_generator/

However, having shipping address displayed may be inconvenient if you sell services and the payment takes place afterwards.

### For services

1) First option for a service would look like this:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=info@test.com&currency_code=EUR&amount=0.01&invoice=112233&custom=something
```

Because you don't specify `item_name` or `item_number`, the buyer will be taken to a different checkout screen, more suitable for services. It will display company name and allow buyer to add description. You can use `invoice` and/or `custom` parameters to specify what the payment is for. However, I haven't found a way yet to make PayPal display invoice number, custom field, or pre-fill description input, so that the buyer would also see what he is paying for.

2) Second option for services is to combine `item_name` and `no_shipping=1` parameters:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?&cmd=_xclick&business=info@test.com&currency_code=EUR&amount=0.01&item_name=Test description&no_shipping=1
```

This will take the buyer to the physical items checkout screen, but without shipping address. It will not allow buyer to add description, but at least it will show the text from `item_name` parameter in cart (drop-down menu in top/right corner). It's not the best location to display services payment details, but it's something.

**PayPal's documentation on the buttons/links:**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

### PayPal.me

PayPal.me is a relatively new service specially designed for payments through simple links. Unfortunately it doesn't allow (as of today) to specify what the payment is for. Not by the seller, nor by the buyer. You can't specify it as a parameter and there is no description field on the checkout page. Although PayPal.me has prettier URLs and checkout screen, for the above reason it is currently more suitable for exchanging money with family and friends than for sales.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they're already logged in:

`https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_send-money&nav=1&email=FOO@BAR.COM`

will load

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's also a way to set the amount?

Comment: It appears this no longer works, at least with the new PayPal UI.

Comment: With the new PayPal business page, a request is composed like so
https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/fi?recipient=email%40test.com&amount=1.23&action=buy&currencyCode=USD&currencyPrecision=2&goods=true&shippingAddressId=&env=hawk&recipientId=&recipientIdType=&clientMetaDataId=b8942d2c7a974778ac320ee3008f09c8
This link cannot, easily, be linked to directly.

Comment: `_send-money` is no longer a valid value for `cmd` parameter.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 2):

You can also make it as link.

1. https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=buynow and create a button
2. Take the html that gets generated

   `<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
   <input type="hidden"` **name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"**`>
   <input type="hidden"` **name="hosted_button_id" value="5RR3ZKSAPS2EY"**`>
   <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
   <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
   </form>`

Then pick out values and construct url like following

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=5RR3ZKSAPS2EY

and you should be done.

You could even go wild and do something like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=5RR3ZKSAPS2EY"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online."></a>
```

**Note:** you could use PayPal.me which is exactly a link to make payments like this one https://www.paypal.me/Vaitkevicius (spare some change...)

Comment: Note about your note: PayPal.me does not allow anything other than amount and currency in the URL. No description, invoice number, custom field, nothing. Which makes it useless for services/goods payments.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "Buy now" button. Did you find a "Pay now" button? The Mass pay option on PayPal seems to be what you need.

Comment: Can you include an example URL construct?